# What is the best way to test Silverlight UI

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, testing, coded-ui-tests

I wanna a feedback how to write and maintain UI Test

I use unit test for ViewModel logic, and sometime functionnal test (with Specflow or something like that). But what is the best for UI testing ?

Visual studio 2010 test (Coded Ui Tests) ? Watin, white, selenium ? or other ways ?

Any feedback and advice are welcome

Answer (score 0):

We faced this issue in our current project: SL UI will be introduced in the next release.
After research made (not by me, unfortunately) it came out that no tool now is OK to work with.

Candidates were: CodedUI tests, TestComplete and Telerik UI testing studio.

**However**, by release of SL5 Microsoft and Telerik promise to provide much better support for SL UI testing, so we decided to wait for this.

NOTE: as we use Telerik controls and our layout is extremely complicated, this could be the cause of poor performance of testing tools, so you'd check it on your own.

Still I'd recommend to wait till SL5 is released.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, I would recommend Visual Studio 2010 CodedUI Tests. I do not like that I have to include a test-specific dll, and that i have to name every control just for the test; but it seems that it is worth the additional work.

Selenium can only test Silverlight with a plugin. This plugin needs Selenium RC - so, for me it seems outdated.

You can also add the [Ranorex Test Automation Framework](http://www.ranorex.com) to the list of candidates.